# StrokeWidth value in px/em fabricjs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, fabricjs

I am adding a rectangle/circle to the canvas and changing the strokeWidth with a range type input.
What is the value of strokeWidth in px/em/%, if we have strokeWidth:5 and range of strokeWidth(1-10).
Actually I wanted to know how much the actual width increases in px, whenever we try to increase the strokeWidth.

Check the code for example:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1');

$('.add_shape').click(function() {
  var cur_value = $(this).attr('data-rel');
  if (cur_value != '') {
    switch (cur_value) {
      case 'rectangle':
        var rect = new fabric.Rect({
          left: 50,
          top: 50,
          fill: '#aaa',
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
          opacity: 1,
          stroke: '#000',
          strokeWidth: 1,
          noScaleCache: false,
          strokeUniform: true,
        });
        canvas.add(rect);
        canvas.setActiveObject(rect);
        break;
      case 'circle':
        var circle = new fabric.Circle({
          left: 50,
          top: 50,
          fill: '#aaa',
          radius: 50,
          opacity: 1,
          stroke: '#000',
          strokeWidth: 1,
          noScaleCache: false,
          strokeUniform: true
        });
        canvas.add(circle);
        canvas.setActiveObject(circle);
        break;
    }
  }
});

/* Control the border  */
$('#control_border').change(function() {
  var cur_value = parseInt($(this).val());
  var activeObj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if (activeObj == undefined) {
    alert('Please select the Object');
    return false;
  }
  activeObj.set({
    strokeWidth: cur_value
  });
  canvas.renderAll();
});
button {
  max-resolution: 10px;
  height: 30px;
}

div {
  margin: 10px
}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.7.0/fabric.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button class="add_shape" data-rel="circle">Add Circle</button>
  <button class="add_shape" data-rel="rectangle">Add Rectangle</button>
  <label class="control-label">Border</label>
  <input id="control_border" type="range" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0" />
</div>

<canvas id="canvas1" width="600" height="300" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @AlonEitan , I have updated the the Question.

Comment: I've read your question 3 times and it's still not really clear to me what you're asking. Perhaps try rephrasing and updating your provided code as a working snippet?

Comment: @melchiar ,If I am increasing the strokewidth(1-10) value. The Border width is increasing. I wanted to know that borderwidth in px/em/% units

Comment: What do you mean by px/em/% units?

Comment: @melchiar If we increase the strokewidth by 5.
As seen, the borderwidth increase is not 5px or 5em or 5%.
So I wanted to know whenever we increase strokewidth by 1.
How much increase has happened actually

Comment: K, so you want to know the difference between the new strokeWidth and the previous strokeWidth? Can't you just subtract the values to find the amount of increase? (newStrokeWidth - oldStrokeWidth)

Comment: @melchair , you percepted wrongly.

Comment: @melchair check the image I have added. 
I just wanted to know the size of width (Red in Color) in px/em

Comment: @melchair you are subtracting the strokewidth , I get it.
But the difference we get (the value we get) is not px.

Comment: The px width of a stroke changes depending on zoom,  screen resolution and your export size, not just strokeWidth. Similarly, em is a unit related to typography size which your stroke isn't being used for. Perhaps you can explain why you want those units?

Comment: Ok got it. But still can we find that width (? on picture) at  particular instant.

Comment: @melchiar Actually there is a video Iframe, seen in the picture.
whenever I increase stroke width to that video iframe.
Stroke of left and Top are overlapped on video iframe.
If I get the width of stroke in px, I can dynamically set the top and left of video iframe.

Comment: k, so it's CSS pixels you're wanting in order to calculate the onscreen size of the object. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I believe what you're wanting is to calculate the on screen CSS pixel size of your object and stroke. This changes according to the canvas's zoom level so that needs to be accounted for in the calculation.

This will give you the total object dimensions in CSS pixels (including stroke):

```
var zoom =  canvas.getZoom();
var totalWidth = obj.getScaledWidth() * zoom;
var totalHeight = obj.getScaledHeight() * zoom;
```

This will give you just the stroke size in CSS pixels:

```
var zoom =  canvas.getZoom();
var strokeX = obj.strokeWidth * obj.scaleX * zoom;
var strokeY = obj.strokeWidth * obj.scaleY * zoom;
```

If you're using the `strokeUniform` property, the stroke size won't be affected by the object's scale, so you can just do this.

```
var zoom =  canvas.getZoom();
var strokeSize = obj.strokeWidth * zoom;
```

Also, if your object uses a `paintFirst` value of `stroke` then half of the stroke width will be covered by the fill, so you'll need to multiply your result by 0.5 to get the visible stroke width.

Comment: one question @melchiar,
what is obj.scaleX and ScaleY?
I researched this but not got any perfect answer.
and why we used here

Comment: When you use the controls to resize an object it changes the scale values . We use it here because the width of each axis is determined by multiplying the strokeWidth by the scale factor for that axis.

Answer (score 0):

Just add two lines:-
1.`<div id="strokeValue"></div>` in html
2.`document.getElementById('strokeValue').innerHTML=cur_value;` at  `/* Control the border  */` in Javascript

here is the full code:-

```html
<style>

button {
  max-resolution: 10px;
  height: 30px;
}

div {
  margin: 10px
}
</style>

<div>
  <button class="add_shape" data-rel="circle">Add Circle</button>
  <button class="add_shape" data-rel="rectangle">Add Rectangle</button>
  <label class="control-label">Border</label>
  <input id="control_border" type="range" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0" />
</div>

<div id="strokeValue"></div>

<canvas id="canvas1" width="600" height="300" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.7.0/fabric.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1');
    
    $('.add_shape').click(function() {
      var cur_value = $(this).attr('data-rel');
      if (cur_value != '') {
        switch (cur_value) {
          case 'rectangle':
            var rect = new fabric.Rect({
              left: 50,
              top: 50,
              fill: '#aaa',
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
              opacity: 1,
              stroke: '#000',
              strokeWidth: 1,
              noScaleCache: false,
              strokeUniform: true,
            });
            canvas.add(rect);
            canvas.setActiveObject(rect);
            break;
          case 'circle':
            var circle = new fabric.Circle({
              left: 50,
              top: 50,
              fill: '#aaa',
              radius: 50,
              opacity: 1,
              stroke: '#000',
              strokeWidth: 1,
              noScaleCache: false,
              strokeUniform: true
            });
            canvas.add(circle);
            canvas.setActiveObject(circle);
            break;
        }
      }
    });
    
    /* Control the border  */
    $('#control_border').change(function() {
      var cur_value = parseInt($(this).val());
      var activeObj = canvas.getActiveObject();
      document.getElementById('strokeValue').innerHTML=cur_value;
      if (activeObj == undefined) {
        alert('Please select the Object');
        return false;
      }
      activeObj.set({
        strokeWidth: cur_value
      });
      canvas.renderAll();
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I wanted to know the width of border which is increased in px/em/% units , when we increase the strokewidth.